# How to properly pad an HTML link?

Tags: html, css

I have this html and css code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
        <style>
            div.container{
                border: 1px solid #F00;
            }
            a.padded
            {
                font-size: 14px;
                font-weight: bold;
                text-decoration: none;
                background-color: #F0F0F0;
                border: 1px solid #666666;
                padding: 15px;
                margin: 10px;
                border-radius: 5px;
                box-shadow: #CCC 2px 2px 2px;
                color: #333333;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <a href="#" class="padded">my padded link</a>
        </div>
        <div>Some other content</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I was expecting the padded link to be contained in it's parent DIV block where the DIV would expand to whatever height of the padded link.  However it seems the link padding is ignored by the DIV and everything else on the page.

Why does this happen and how do I properly pad a link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is, give your anchor tag an `display:block` property.

```
a.padded {
   display: block;
   /* display:inline-block; should 
      work too but is not supported in some version of IE */
}
```

Comment: This works, but if I add display:block then I also have to add floats if I want to have multiple links on the same line?  And then also clears to get the right line breaks in.

Comment: Yes, i think that is the best way if you want it to work on all browsers.

Answer (score 2):

Anchor tags are inline objects.

Add `display: inline-block;` to `.padded.` and it should work.

http://jsfiddle.net/6h7MY/

Answer (score 1):

Because I've asked myself this question recently, [this article](http://www.maxdesign.com.au/articles/inline/) is a big help as to *why* this is happening. The relevant bit is:

```
The W3C’s CSS2 spec states that for Inline, non-replaced elements,
the ‘height’ property doesn’t apply, but the height of the box is given
by the ‘line-height’ property.
```